# How to rename last n columns of dataframe with vector of strings, using rename_with or rename?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, rename

I'm using rename_at, but since it is superseded, I need to find a way to rename n last columns with some vector of strings using rename_with() or rename()

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  a = 1:10,
  b = 1:10,
  c = 1:10,
  d = 1:10,
  e = 1:10
)

new_names <- c("1", "2", "4", "5", "10")

df %>% 
  rename_at(vars(names(.) %>% tail(5)), funs(paste0("", new_names))) # only `funs(new_names)` won't work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `rename_with`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
    rename_with(~ str_c(., new_names), tail(names(.), 5))
# A tibble: 10 x 5
#      a1    b2    c4    d5   e10
#   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1     1     1     1     1     1
# 2     2     2     2     2     2
# 3     3     3     3     3     3
# 4     4     4     4     4     4
# 5     5     5     5     5     5
# 6     6     6     6     6     6
# 7     7     7     7     7     7
# 8     8     8     8     8     8
# 9     9     9     9     9     9
#10    10    10    10    10    10
```

Or with `rename`

```
df %>% 
     rename(!!! setNames(tail(names(.), 5), new_names))
```

---

Or using `rename_at` directly on the `tail` of `names`

```
df %>% 
      rename_at(vars(tail(names(.), 5)), ~ str_c(., new_names))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 x 5
#      a1    b2    c4    d5   e10
#   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1     1     1     1     1     1
# 2     2     2     2     2     2
# 3     3     3     3     3     3
# 4     4     4     4     4     4
# 5     5     5     5     5     5
# 6     6     6     6     6     6
# 7     7     7     7     7     7
# 8     8     8     8     8     8
# 9     9     9     9     9     9
#10    10    10    10    10    10
```

---

if it is to just replace the names

```
df %>% 
    rename_at(vars(tail(names(.), 5)), ~ new_names)
# A tibble: 10 x 5
#     `1`   `2`   `4`   `5`  `10`
#   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1     1     1     1     1     1
# 2     2     2     2     2     2
# 3     3     3     3     3     3
# 4     4     4     4     4     4
# 5     5     5     5     5     5
# 6     6     6     6     6     6
# 7     7     7     7     7     7
# 8     8     8     8     8     8
# 9     9     9     9     9     9
#10    10    10    10    10    10
```

In the example, there are only 5 columns.  Suppose, if it is only the last 3 columns

```
df %>%
   rename_at(vars(tail(names(.), 3)), ~ str_c(., tail(new_names, 3)))
```

---

`funs` take a function, so wrapping with `paste0` or `as.character` does that instead of just a input vector

Comment: @AlvaroMorales it is for evaluation

Answer (score 2):

Base R approach :

```
n <- ncol(df)
names(df)[(n-4):n] <- new_names
df

# A tibble: 10 x 5
#     `1`   `2`   `4`   `5`  `10`
#   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1     1     1     1     1     1
# 2     2     2     2     2     2
# 3     3     3     3     3     3
# 4     4     4     4     4     4
# 5     5     5     5     5     5
# 6     6     6     6     6     6
# 7     7     7     7     7     7
# 8     8     8     8     8     8
# 9     9     9     9     9     9
#10    10    10    10    10    10
```